# indexOf with variable string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this problem with javascript/jQuery, I have this code

```
//settings is the array of options passed to the function
$input = $('#par_kw[ref="'+settings['ref'] +'"]')
var prev = $input.val();
alert(prev + ' : '+settings['new_kw']+' : '+ prev.indexOf(settings['new_kw']));
```

in run time I get messages like :  `maths, computing : maths : -1` always `-1` but when I tried constant `indexOf("maths")` it works and I get `0` or what ever the index of it
can u see what I'm doing wrong?? cause I can't :(

### update

oh well, this is even more confusing :/
I tried JSFIDDLE.net [here](http://jsfiddle.net/katkootable/DXyBY/1/) but it works just fine :(
could it be something wrong in files, because in my project I separate code into 2 file but I kept it simple in one file @ jsfiddle ?!!
but that makes no sense!! where ever the instruction is, I'm making sure that the value is caught correctly in alert!

Comment: Can you make some thing to show on sites like JsFiddle?

Comment: @Adil I don't know this site, but I'll give it a try. wait a sec :)

Comment: Do you want to know the index of the term in the list? If yes, maybe this example can help you http://jsfiddle.net/DXyBY/12/ . If no, I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/DXyBY/9/) for you. Is that thing?

Comment: can you please explain what you did? the alert is the value of input text field which is empty!!

Comment: So, if the field is empty, alert will be shown with an empty string. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/DXyBY/10/)

Comment: what's the point? what if it's not empty, how would that help check if the pressed td text isn't already there?

Comment: i'm sorry, I didn't understand what you want.